# Can't run application from install4j launcher after install has completed

Tags: install4j

I have completed the core functionality of my installer, but need to add the ability for the user to launch the application after it has finished installing.

I have already gained elevated privileges earlier in the install process, but when the installer tries to launch the application it fails with the following error log:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\abc\xyz\xyz 1.2.exe" (in directory "C:\Program Files\abc\xyz"): CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.launching.LaunchHelper.launchOnWindows(LaunchHelper.java:387)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.launching.LaunchHelper.launchApplicationDirectly(LaunchHelper.java:151)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.launching.LaunchHelper.access$000(LaunchHelper.java:33)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.launching.LaunchHelper$2.fetchValue(LaunchHelper.java:110)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.launching.LaunchHelper$2.fetchValue(LaunchHelper.java:107)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.actions.FetchObjectAction.execute(FetchObjectAction.java:14)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionWrapper(HelperCommunication.java:367)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.access$200(HelperCommunication.java:30)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication$1.run(HelperCommunication.java:96)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
... 11 more
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's strange, because the stacktrace shows that process is being launcher by the elevated helper process, so it has elevated privileges. However, why do you want to launch the launcher with elevated privileges? Usually you launch the executable as the user. This is done by changing the "Action elevation type" property of the "Run executable or batch file" action to "Do not elevate".

Comment: I tried launching the executable without elevating the privileges and got the exact same error.

Comment: What if you launch it from a terminal? Does this executable require elevated privileges in its manifest?

Comment: If I launch it from the terminal, it does require administrative privileges.

Comment: If this is generated launcher, try selecting "As invoker" on the "Executable info->Windows manifest options" step of the launcher wizard. The "Run executable" action will provide the privileges.

Comment: Yup! That fixed my issue. Do you want to add this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is generated launcher, try selecting "As invoker" on the "Executable info->Windows manifest options" step of the launcher wizard. The "Run executable" action will provide the privileges.